# How can I add the control chart and gridview in the same email body?

Tags: c#, asp.net

The below code to send gridview in body email. How can I add chart to show in body email too (not by attach).
I try to use "AlternateViews.Add" but gridview was made to disappear.

```
protected void btn_sendmail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

            try
            {
                MailMessage mm = new MailMessage();
                mm.From = new MailAddress("Ttest@xxx.com", "website (Do not reply)");
                mm.To.Add(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailDailyReport"]);
                mm.Subject = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
                mm.Body = "<span style='font-family:Calibri;font-size:12pt;'>Dear all, <br/>";
                mm.Body += "Please find the details of daily production report for " + DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + " in picture below.";
                mm.Body += "<br/>";
                mm.Body += " ";
                mm.Body += GetGridviewData(gvProdReport);

                mm.Body += "Group by";
                mm.Body += GetSubGridviewData(gvSubTotal);
                mm.Body += "<br/>";
                mm.Body += "If you have any questions or comments do feel free to reply all.";
                mm.Body += "</splan>";

                

                mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
                SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailServer"]);
                SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("Ttest@xxx.com", "Call5191");

                SmtpServer.Send(mm);
                lbl_result.Text = "Send complete!";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lbl_result.Text = "Send incomplete! message :" + ex.ToString();
                lbl_result.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            }
}
```

Comment: Can you please give more information on what did not work and what you've tried

Answer (score 0):

Check this link:

[Send Chart in Email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31800959/send-chart-in-email)

Step 1: Create Chart

Step 2: After the create chart to an image base64string

Step 3: Pass the base64string in your mail

Step 4: Send and check your mailbox

Also, If you need to send grid view data then you need the set bunch of the data with HTML  and then send.

https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/How-to-send-GridView-data-in-email-in-ASPNet.aspx